# Netbeans Error a Valid XML

Tags: java, xml, netbeans, ide

In these days , I confront a BIG problem , when I opened my project , a form can't be displayed and no code is showing !! just a error displayed telling me that :
netbeans the form file does not contain valid xml

Please Help

Comment: Show us the XML code.

Comment: It's not matter of content , the application was running properly but the problem has occurred because when I was working on my project my laptop shut down accidentally , and when I open my project I compile it then I got that problem , which is I found it later as a bug in the officiel website of Netbeans !!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I implemented a Netbeans Swing application, but I do remember that when you create a form, it creates an auxiliary file with xml (perhaps the suffix is ".form" or something similar, but I don't remember for sure).

In any case, close Netbeans and search the project directory for the auxiliary file (the file prefix should be your class name). Open it up in a text editor, and hopefully it will be obvious how the xml got corrupted and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

## Workaround

1. Remove the newly created form
2. Try to re-create it
3. The new `foo.form` file will contain valid data :)